# Can '\' be in a Python string?

Tags: python, string, pycharm

I program in Python in PyCharm and whenever I write '\' as a string it says that the following statements do nothing. For example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KGUn.png]

Is there a way to fix this and make it work?
Thanks.

Comment: Notice in the first line of your dictionary, you have an error at the end of the line?  It's because the `\` character is escaping the `'` that follows it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to double the backslash:

```
'/-\\'
```

as a *single* backslash has special meaning in a Python string as the start of an escape sequence. A double `\\` results in the string containing a single backslash:

```
>>> print '/-\\'
/-\
```

If the backslash is *not* the last character in the string, you could use a `r''` raw string as well:

```
>>> print r'\-/'
\-/
```

Comment: When I write '/-\\' at the console it does show as '/-\', but when I run the program and tell it to print the 'A' list it show '/-\\'.

Comment: @user3422569: don't confuse the *representation* with the contents. If you don't use `print`, just echo the value in the interpreter, `repr()` is called and the value is shown as a Python string literal, escaped for copying and pasting.

Comment: @user3422569: Compare `print A` with `print repr(A)` and see if there really are one or two backslashes.

Answer (score 7):

You need to scape them to be in the string, for example:

```
>>>s='\\'
>>>print s
\
```

You can also use the `r` (raw string) modifier in front of the string to include them easily but they can't end with an odd number of backslash. You can read more about [string literals on the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).