# Why python is putting "\\" in my string before single quotes

Tags: python, string, format

Code where the problem occurs:

```
    def updateEmpresaSetXEqualsToByCnpj(self, nomeColuna, valor, cnpj):
        query = (r"UPDATE empresa_cliente SET {0} = {1} WHERE cnpj_emp = '{2}';".format(nomeColuna, valor, cnpj))
```

I'm sending a string, a int and a string. The last param must have single quotes cause SQL SERVER syntax but the python is putting double back slash before each single quotes.
e.g.

```
UPDATE empresa_cliente SET regime_tributacao_federal = 1 WHERE cnpj_emp = \\'33333222000111\\';
```

When the correct query should be

```
UPDATE empresa_cliente SET regime_tributacao_federal = 1 WHERE cnpj_emp = '3333222000111';
```

Comment: Please give us the original values of those variables

Comment: how are you passing the value for cnpj?

Comment: So you close single quotes before the value, prematurely closing quotes. It is likely trying to save you from yourself....

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx the values of the vars are *regime_tributacao_federal*, *1* and *3333222000111* respectively

Comment: Just using string handling, it works fine for me, tested on 3.6 and 2.7.  Try printing the value of `query` immediately after you construct it.

Comment: @Dan, I'm passing the values from here `EliteDB.updateEmpresaSetXEqualsToByCnpj('regime_tributacao_federal', regime_tributario, empresa.cnpj)` where **empresa.cnpj** is a string like **3333222000111**

Comment: @cdarke, I did it and and the value printed was: `UPDATE empresa_cliente SET regime_tributacao_federal = 1 WHERE cnpj_emp = '3333222000111';` what is right, but looking for Pycharm Debug the value continues with \\ before each **'**         
consequently the query is not executed

Comment: Maybe its a feature of PyCharm then?

Comment: @cdarke I think it is. I posted an answer to explain more. Perhaps OP is doing some extra formatting too?

Comment: If your query fails then it is for some other reason, it appears you are being distracted by the way that Pycharm is displaying your string in Debug.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384471/why-does-pycharm-use-double-backslash-to-indicate-escaping and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207000145-Escape-Quote-Placed-Automatically-in-String-Why-

Comment: @cdarke you're right. I was distracted by Pycharm Debug. My real problem was on another part of code. I wasn't used to use `commit()` sentence after `execute(query)` sentence.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

```
r"UPDATE empresa_cliente SET {0} = {1} WHERE cnpj_emp = '{2}';"
```

`r""` suspends escape sequences. If you're working interactively and using `r""` don't worry about the double `\\` when you write to files, it writes only one `\` check that with `print`.

For the second string:

```
'UPDATE empresa_cliente SET regime_tributacao_federal = 1 WHERE cnpj_emp = \\\'33333222000111\\\';'
```

Here's what you've not probably noticed:

```
>>> "\\\'wwww"
"\\'wwww"
>>> print("\\\'wwww")
\'wwww
```

If you would, change it to this, it's essentially the same maybe aesthetically better:

```
"UPDATE empresa_cliente SET regime_tributacao_federal = 1 WHERE cnpj_emp = '33333222000111';"
```

It's also possible that you're passing you strings to another formatting  before you write them elsewhere, check for that.